# Searching Greek and Hebrew texts in Emacs with isearch while ignoring accents and diacritics

Tags: org-mode, isearch

I have a number of text and org documents that contain Greek and Hebrew text. I want to be able to search these in Emacs using isearch but I also want Emacs to ignore all accents and diacritics. I found a solution to this problem years ago but forgot what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> To toggle whether or not the search will consider similar and equivalent characters as a match, type M-s '.

Source : https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Special-Isearch.html

Comment: It appears that one cannot disable character folding in a regexp search, only a regular search.